# Resolv::DNS - How to handle timeouts, errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resolv

I'm using the following function in Ruby on Rails:

```
  def isGoogleEmailAddress?(email_domain)
    Resolv::DNS.open({:nameserver=>["8.8.8.8"]}) do |r|
      mx = r.getresources(email_domain,Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::MX)
      if mx.any? {|server| server.exchange.to_s.downcase.include? "google"} then
        return true
      end
      return false
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to handle the issue where Resolv fails, timeouts, errors etc?

Answer (score -2):

Look through the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/) for the Resolv class and add exception handlers for the various errors/exceptions the class can raise.

They're easy to pick out. Look for classes ending in error and timeout.